# Removing "semi" duplicates on an inner join in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, inner-join, distinct

I'm trying to join two tables, one which describes species and another while has the parent/child relationship between the species. Unfortunately, there are multiple "semi" duplicates that cause my query to return more than one row per taxon.

An example of the taxon relation table that uses TID and ParentTID fields:

```
TID AuthorityID ParentTID
1        1          4     <-- offending row (note tid, parenttid)
1        1          2
2        1          2
3        2          2
1        2          4     <-- offending row (note tid, parenttid)
```

The taxon definition table contains text fields with the name of the taxon. In this case the duplicate parentID of '4' is giving me more than one row, even when using DISTINCT. My query is below:

```
SELECT SciName, rankID, MAX(parenttid) AS parentID, taxaenumtree.tid,
MAX(taxauthid) AS taid FROM taxaenumtree INNER JOIN taxa ON taxa.tid =
taxaenumtree.tid WHERE rankID > 1
AND SciName NOT LIKE "Animalia"
GROUP BY taxaenumtree.tid
```

**Result Set (prior to joining on TID with another table):**

```
TID   AuthorityID  ParentTID
1         1            4             
2         1            2           
3         2            2
```

**I'd like to obtain something like (post-join):**

```
TaxonID FullName       RankID ParentID TaxonAuthority
1      Magnoliophyta   10       4           1   
2      Plantae         10       2           1
3      Cupressacae     30       2           2

and so on, producing 1 row for each taxon with the highest ParentID.
```

For each record, with only one row per unique taxon.

Comment: show the sample (complete) and the result you want obtain

Comment: Hi, @scaisEdge - I added an example and clarified the table. The taxon table (not shown) just has a name field and TID.

Comment: @Strawberry a continuation of results where each taxon defined by a TID has a name, rankID, parentID (which is the highest for that TID), and a taxonAuthority. My current issue now is the various TaxonAuthority versions that replicate existing information (as highlighted in the example table).

Comment: @Strawberry, is it more obvious now? Sorry I'm not conveying this accurately. I've added a result set that has the values I want from the example data set above without considering the join.

Comment: @Strawberry, fixed!

Comment: OK, so going way back to the beginning, yes - along with clarifying your PRIMARY KEY, you need to establish some kind of ordering criteria.

Comment: @Strawberry, great - I just moved everything to a temporary table that has ordering in it and I'll approach it that way. Be back in a bit with an update - I feel like I should just be able to group on TID and ParentTID.

Comment: That would return 4 rows, not 3. :-(.

Comment: @Strawberry, if the data is ordered I should just be able to select the MIN or MAX value for the ordered field I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured that the best solution to this issue is to order the data set, following suggestion by @Strawberry and operate on this by grouping each ID and parent ID pair, selecting the minimum ordered value for each, setting that as a new field for each group and then deleting all rows for which the ordered value and minimum value are not equal.